# Why does this function that take flat array take so long to make it a nested array?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, tree

I have a project in php that I am working on where I am taking a flat array and making it a nested array.  The result is working but is too slow when my tree gets bigger.  I just don't know why it is being so slow or what to do.

```
$this->tree = [
    [ 'id' => 1, 'parent_id' => null ],
    [ 'id' => 2, 'parent_id' => 1 ],
    [ 'id' => 3, 'parent_id' => 1 ],
    [ 'id' => 4, 'parent_id' => 3 ],
    [ 'id' => 5, 'parent_id' => 4 ],
];

// expected result
//  [ 'id' => 1, 'parent_id' => null, 'children' => [
//      [ 'id' => 2, 'parent_id' => 1, 'children' => [] ],
//      [ 'id' => 3, 'parent_id' => 1, 'children' => [
//          [ 'id' => 4, 'parent_id' => 3, 'children' => [
//              [ 'id' => 5, 'parent_id' => 4, 'children' => [] ],
//          ] ],
//      ] ],
//  ] ];


public function make_tree_nested( $base = null ) {
    if ( is_null( $base ) ) {
        $base = $this->get_base( $this->tree );
        if ( is_null( $base ) ) return null;
    }
    $base['children'] = array_map(
        function( $child ) {
            return $this->make_tree_nested( $child );
        },
        $this->get_children( $base )
    );
    return $base;
}

private function get_base( $tree ) {
    foreach( $tree as $group ) {
        if ( is_null( $group['parent_id'] ) ) {
            return $group;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private function get_children( $parent ) {
    return array_values( array_filter(
        $this->tree,
        function( $group ) use ( $parent ) {
            return $group['parent_id'] === $parent['id'];
        }
    ) );
}
```

Comment: First of all, stop using arrays as trees. Use objects instead. At least they have more de-referency behavior making this entire process a lot simpler and sans all the function overhead. Second, you don't need to traverse the entire world from scratch to do one thing. Use memoization.

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou Sherif.  My solution is to change how my data is structured and simplify. Now I remove extra functions and recursion.

Comment: This isn't much of a helpful/educational answer.